# List reset in a "for" loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reset

guys i'm trying to do this program where i have to take a list and separate all the non unique elements and put it in a list without the changing the order of it.
for example 
[1,2,3,1,3]=[1,3,1,3]
[5,5,5,5]=[5,5,5,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]=[]

So for this, I did the program in python and put some flags to help me know where i'm doing wrong.So in the program i tried to reset the list3 value( after deleting an element of it inside a loop and exiting it) but it wouldn't let me do it.so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you guys very much.

```
list1=[1,2,3,1,3]
list2=[]
d=0
m=0
l=len(list1)
print(l)
for x in range(0,l):
    print('for loop')
    list3=list1  # I used this to reset the list3 to list1 and use it in the loop but it wouldn't reset
    print('this is the reset of list 3',list3)
    m=list1[x]
    print(m,x)
    print(list3[x])
    del (list3[x])

    while True:
        print('while loop',list3[d])

        if m==list3[d]:
            print('its here')
            list2.append(m)
            print('this is list2: ',list2)
        d+=1

        if d==lenght(list3)-1:
            print('its here22222')
            break
print(list2)

# my results were

5
for loop
this is the reset of list 3 [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
1 0
1
while loop 2
while loop 3
while loop 1
its here
this is list2:  [1]
its here22222
for loop
this is the reset of list 3 [2, 3, 1, 3]
3 1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: list3= list1 is not copying list1, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
#list1=[5,5,5,5,5]
list1=[1,2,3,1,3]
#list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[]

for num in list1:
    if list1.count(num) > 1:
        list2.append(num)

print(list2)
```

Comment: it does work. i know the count function. i used it too. but i just don't get why the list3 in the 9th line doesn't reset the list3 to list1. Thanks a lot @dovo36.  :)

Comment: Oh, ok.  It's as paisonco said above.  list3=list1 makes list3 point to the same memory as list1.  So then they are 2 different labels for the same thing.

If you want to copy list1, overwriting list3, then read that link he gave you, it shows the different ways that can be done.

Comment: thanks a lot @davo36. that really helped me out